# How to set DataFrame column values conditionally without a loop in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have the following Pandas DataFrame:

[image]

(My original DataFrame is a lot bigger than the one in this example.)

I need to add another column (col3) to this DataFrame and values of col3 will be set based on following conditions:

- If col1 > col2, value of col3 will be set to 0 on that row.
- If col1 == col2, value of col3 will be set to 1 on that row.
- If col1 < col2, value of col3 will be set to 2 on that row.

The above DataFrame will look as the following after this operation:

[image]

Is there a way to do this without looping through the DataFrame?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do `sign` from `numpy`

```
df['col3']=np.sign((df.col2-df.col1))+1
```

Comment: Just great! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can do `np.select`:

```
df['col3'] = np.select((df['col1'] > df['col2'], df['col1'] < df['col2']),
                       (0, 2), 1)
```

Or use `np.sign`:

```
df['col3'] = np.sign(df['col2']-df['col1']) + 1
```

Comment: np.select is a god way as well. Thank you!